# How to group by a dataframe of a specific class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have one dataframe with this schema:

```
|-- Agreement_A1: string (nullable = true)
|-- Line_A1: string (nullable = true)
|-- Line_A2: string (nullable = true)
```

I create a new dataframe with this code:

```
val df2 = df.map(row => new MapResultRequestLine().apply(row))(Encoders.bean(classOf[AgreementLine]))
```

Function apply() is this:

```
public AgreementLine apply(Row row) {
        AgreementLine agrLine = new AgreementLine();
        agrLine.Agreement_A1 = row.getAs("Agreement_A1");
        Line res = new Line();
        res.Line_A1 = row.getAs("Line_A1");
        res.Line_A2 = row.getAs("Line_A2");
        agrLine.line = res 
        return agrLine;
    }
```

Class AgreementLine looks like this:

```
public class AgreementLine{
    public String agreementCrocCode;
    public Line line;
}
```

Class Line is this:

```
public class Line{
    public String Line_A1;
    public String Line_A2;
}
```

How to group df2 so the result dataframe had Agreement_A1 column and the list of Line?

I have tried it this way:

```
val groupedDF = df2.groupBy($"Agreement_A1").agg(collect_set((array($"line"))).as("lines"))
```

But it shows an error "cannot resolve '`Agreement_A1`' given input columns: [];"

Comment: df2 is a dataset of type `AgreementLine` which doesn't have `Agreement_A1` in the class. You tried to `groupBy` on a column (Agreement_A1) that doesn't exist in df2.  You can check the schema of a dataset using `df2.printSchema`

Comment: printSchema shows only empty brackets "()". Although Count() shows that there are rows

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
val df2 = df.map(row => new MapResultRequestLine().apply(row))(Encoders.bean(classOf[AgreementLine]))
```

scala doesn't show the data type, so you think it's a DataFrame(as DataSet[Row]).

But actually, it's a DataSet(as DataSet[AgreementLine]). And thanks for your encoder, it has lost all the schema, that's the reason why your `df2.printSchema` return the empty result.

Thus, when you call `df2.groupBy($"Agreement_A1")`, it will throw the Exception because there is no column named "Agreement_A1".

Obviously, the solution is to update schema of your DataSet(df2 in your case).

And sadly, I have no idea how to do with this(I'm a Rookie as well).

My only solution is to convert the dataset back to RDD[Row](mention it is RDD[AgreementLine] if you want to use df2.rdd), and build a new DataFrame with custom schema.

Hope you'll get a better solution.